# Assistance with a PseudoRandom Function?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm currently working on an encryption project, and I correctly implemented a Caesarian function in my program, but I need to implement another encryption method.

*Instructions: We will use a modified version called Pseudo-random offset. We won’t need to pre-distribute a booket, just a password, and those are shorter and don’t need to be written down. The password is then used to seed the python random number generator, as described above. You should start with the Caesarian code, but instead of creating one offset at the beginning of the function, create a new one for every single character.*

Below is my Code for the Caesarian. Can anyone provide an example for maybe one character in the code so I can kind of follow along with what's going on? I'm new to python and am still learning.

```
def Caesarian(fin, fout, encrypt_or_decrypt_choice, alphabet):
    # Determine the offset by generating a random number in the correct range.
    # This will be the same random number, if the password sent to random.seed is the same.
    offset = random.randrange(1,len(alphabet))
    if encrypt_or_decrypt_choice=='d':
        offset = -offset
    print "Using the secret offset of", offset

    # Read every line of the input file.
    for line1 in fin:
        # Alter each character of the line1, putting the result into line2.
        line2 = ""
        for c in line1:
            if c in alphabet:
                pos1 = alphabet.find(c)
                pos2 = (pos1+offset)%len(alphabet)
                line2 += alphabet[pos2]
        # Write each resulting line2 to the output file.
        fout.write(line2)
```

Answer (score 3):

In the Ceaser cipher, you shift each character by a constant, fixed amount.

The [Vigenère cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigenere_cipher) is an improvement upon that, by shifting each letter within a small group by a fixed amount. For example, a key of `123` could mean to "shift by one, then by two, then by three, and then repeat", so the message "aaaaaa" would be encrypted as "bcdbcd".

The Vigenère cipher shares a weakness with the Ceaser cipher - it's possible to do calculate the statistics for which letter patterns are most common, and use them to optimize a brute-force search for the key.

What you're building is slightly more complex - a simple stream cipher. The goal here is to encrypt each character by a different amount - so it's *almost* a one-time pad, but without the overhead of transferring an extremely large key.

Now take a look at Python's `random` module:

```
>>> import random
>>> random.choice(range(100))
42
>>> random.choice(range(100))
46
>>> random.choice(range(100))
92
```

As you see, each value is different. If we were to re-run Python, we would get a different series of numbers. If the numbers were truly random, they would be useless for this method of encryption, as the receiver wouldn't be able to recreate the same stream.

Seeding the pseudo-random number generator allows us to fix the initial state so that the results are predictable:

```
>>> random.seed(5)
>>> random.choice(range(100))
62
>>> random.choice(range(100))
74
```

And now if I re-seed it, we'll get the same exact numbers:

```
>>> random.seed(5)
>>> random.choice(range(100))
62
>>> random.choice(range(100))
74
```

To migrate your original code, you need to change your initial calculation of the `offset` to setting the seed, and then update the offset for each character.

(Here's my attempt at updating the pasted code):

```
def streamCipher(fin, fout, encrypt_or_decrypt_choice, alphabet, seed):
    # Seed random with the shared secret
    random.seed(seed)

    # Read every line of the input file.
    for line1 in fin:
        # Alter each character of the line1, putting the result into line2.
        line2 = ""
        for c in line1:
            if c in alphabet:
                # Determine the offset by generating a random number in the correct range.
                # This will return the same sequence of random numbers, if the seed is the same.
                offset = random.randrange(1,len(alphabet))
                if encrypt_or_decrypt_choice=='d':
                    offset = -offset
                pos1 = alphabet.find(c)
                pos2 = (pos1+offset)%len(alphabet)
                line2 += alphabet[pos2]
        # Write each resulting line2 to the output file.
        fout.write(line2)
```

Comment: In `StreamCipher` you're using `offset` before setting it... And the Mersenne Twister that drives the random module is completely deterministic and "completely unsuitable for cryptographic purposes." to quote the documentation.

Comment: Good catch on that - I'll update it. I purposely attempted to stay out of the details of cryptographically-secure pseudo-random number generators and the attacks on the algorithm - my goal was to give an idea for the motivation of the algorithm and explaining how it works. It's most definitely insecure.

Comment: +1 for the idea though, very nice! For python 3 the docs advise to use [ssl.RAND_bytes](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/ssl.html#ssl.RAND_bytes). But that doesn't exist in 2.7.